# insert result of query into another query in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I need to insert query result as input of another query
Here is the code that I have tried,Please I need help immediately
I need to get id from query1 and insert it in query2 as $id

```
class Get_db extends CI_Model{
    public function get_All(){
        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT name,id from companydetails");
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function getBranches(){
        $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT branches.name FROM branches WHERE           branches.companyid=$id ");
        return $query2->result();
    }
}
```

I need to get id from query1 and insert it in query2 as $id

Comment: If the two tables are in the same database, you only need one query.  The key is joining tables.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: get_all() will return u array of data.... from that u can send array of id's as a parameter in getBranches() use foreach create an array of branches and return that

Comment: but I need results separately, because I have anothsr usage

Comment: I got your point, but i have no Idea how to do it

Comment: user3713740 I got your idea please help me

Answer (score 1):

The method get_All() returns an object, so you could use :

```
$resultQuery1 = get_All();

$output = array();

foreach($resultQuery1 as $q)
    $output[$q->id] = getBranches($q->id);
```

In the getBranches method you should accept a parameter

```
public function getBranches($id) {...}
```

The $output variable is an array with all the results of the getBranches method.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
    <?php 
$this->db->select('name,id')
    ->from('companydetails');
$qry = $this->db->get();
$res = $qry->result();

foreach($res as $val){
    $this->db->select('name')
        ->from('branches')
        ->where('companyid', $val->id);
    $qry2 = $this->db->get();
    $res2 = $qry->result();
}   

return $res2;

?>
```

the **$res** array is the executed result of the first query that is going to put as input to the second query

Comment: under a function and access it in controller as,
$res = $this->model_name->function_name(parameters);

Answer (score 0):

This will do it...

```
      public function get_All()
      {
                $this->db->select('name, id');
                $query = $this->db->get('companydetails');
                if ($query->num_rows () > 0)
                {

                         $result = $query->result();
                           foreach($result as $company)
                           {
                                    $company->branches = $this->getBranches($company->id);                                       
                           }

                          return $result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
      }

      public function getBranches($id)
      {
                $query = $this->db->get_where('branches', array('id' => $id));
                return $query->result();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in **one simple function**. Use **`JOIN`**-

```
<?php
class Get_db extends CI_Model
{
   public function get_company_branches()
   {
      $this->db->select('companydetails.name','companydetails.id','branches.name');
      $this->db->from('companydetails');
      $this->db->join('branches', 'companydetails.id = branches.companyid');

      $query = $this->db->get();

      $result = array();
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
          $result = $query->result_array();

      echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);    // Your expected result
   }
}
```

**OR** if you don't want to use **JOIN** and go w.r.t your question asked, then here you go:

**Model:**

```
...
...
public function get_All()
{
    $this->db->select("id","name");
    $this->db->from("companydetails");

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function getBranches($id)
{
    $this->db->select("name");
    $this->db->from("branches");
    $this->db->where("companyid", $id)

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
...
...
public function somename()
{
    $companies = $this->get_db->get_All();

    $branches = array();
    foreach($companies as $company)
    {
       $branches[] = $this->get_db->getBranches($company->id);
    }

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($branches);   // Expected result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
 public function home(){
        $this->load->model('get_company_model');
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_all();

        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
        $this->load->view('view_content');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }
```

model

```
 public function get_All(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name,id from companydetails");
        return $query->result();

    }
    public function get_branch($companyID){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name,id from branches WHERE companyid='".$companyID."'");
        return $query->result();

    }
```

view

```
<div>
        <ol class="tree">
    <li>
        <label for="folder1"><?=$row->name?></label> <input type="checkbox"  id="folder1" /> 
        <ol>
              <?php
                $myresult=$this->get_company_model->get_branch($row->id);
                foreach($myresult as $row2):
                  ?>  
            <li class="file"><a href="#"><?=$row2->name?></a></li>
            <?php
                 endforeach;
                ?>
</ol>
    </div>

    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
```